# Execute a command (TortoiseHG) through cmd remotely (PsExec)

Tags: cmd, mercurial, tortoisehg, psexec

Basically I want to use PsExec in order to navigate to a specificar folder in a remote computer and performe "hg update branch". I've tried to create the following batch but I'm not able to perform the command:

```
psexec cmd.exe /c "cd C:\Project\hg update Test"
```

It's reading as the "hg update Test" was a folder instead of command to be done... I'm tilting over here and this seems like a basic thing :(. How do I pass the "hg update branch" as cmd command through PsExec?

Comment: `psexec cmd.exe /c "cd ... ; hg update branch"`?

Comment: that doesn't work, in cmd you don't separate folder path with a ";" from the argument

Comment: It worked for me with `&&` instead of `;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change directory, just tell HG what path to operate in:

```
psexec cmd.exe /c "hg update -R C:\Project\ Test"
```

The help says:

> ```
>  -R --repository REPO   repository root directory ...
> ```